# No type warnings where I would expect them

Tags: typescript

Im declaring an object as follows:

```
const x: { str: string, num: number } = {
    str: str,
    num: not_a_num
  };
```

The point is: not_a_num is NOT a number but a string. I would expect the compiler to throw an error; instead, I get an object with two string properties.

Also, I declare a function:

```
store(array: Array<{ str: string, num: number }>): Promise<any> { //... }
```

in which typeof(array[0].num) resolves to "string" when I pass an array containing the object x as param.

My question is: Why don't I get any compiler warnings/errors from this? What is the point in making type annotations if I don't get warned if I try to pass something I obviously don't want to pass (as I explicitly stated that a number has to be passed)?
I feel that I have some fundamental misunderstanding here.

Greetings and thank you!

Comment: how is `not_a_num` declared ? The following code produces an error : http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20str%20%3D%20%22%22%3B%0D%0Alet%20not_a_num%20%3D%20%22%22%3B%0D%0Aconst%20x%3A%20%7B%20str%3A%20string%2C%20num%3A%20number%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20str%3A%20str%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20num%3A%20not_a_num%0D%0A%7D%3B

Comment: Huh, youre right.

Not_a_num is declared as:
this.formGroup[index].controls.qty.value

which is an angular statement that returns a string. Maybe its an Angular-Problem?

Still, the second question applies: Why does a function accept the object containing a string?

Comment: (Simplification: Its the value (which is a property) of an angular formcontrol.)

Comment: Not_a_num  is probably of type `any` which means that it can be assigned to anything, so an object of type `{str: string, num: any }` is assignable to your type

Comment: Oh wow, okay, that seems legit.
Can you recommend a source where I can get a deeper understanding on this?

What I don't get is why I can explictly state im expecting a number and still receive a string because someone on the outside decided to pass "any" which then resolves to a string. Isn't that contrary to the whole point of typing?

Comment: That is why `any` should be avoided, I would recommend enabling `noImplicitAny`. As far as type compatibility is concerned, I don't have a book to recommend but fellow stackoverflower @basarat has some books on typescript that you could start with https://www.gitbook.com/@basarat. I personally have not read them but they have come up in my searches quite often

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `not_a_num` is typed as `any`. And `any` is compatible with any other type.

```
let str = "";
let not_a_num:any = "";

const xWithAny: { str: string, num: any } = {
    str: str,
    num: not_a_num
};
const x: { str: string, num: number }  = xx; // valid
```

Type compatibility is determined based on the compatibility of each component, so in the above code `xWithAny` is compatible with `x` since the `str` property has the same type, and `num:any`  can be assigned to `num:number`.

The problem is that at runtime `not_a_num` can have any valid value (since it is of type `any`) and thus `num` can end up being a string.

Generally you should avoid `any` and if you use it you should make a conscious decision to type things as `any`. The typescript compiler can help a bit, by enabling `noImplicitAny`.